# How can i filter a List of Objects with a List of Objects after an Enum with Streams

Tags: java, list, java-stream

My Problem is the following:

I have a List of Requests and the Requests in the list also have a List of Actions. In the Actions i have an Enum. I want to remove all Requests out of the top List if one of the Actions has the Enum DENIED.
I have a Solution but i keep thinking there must be a better solution for that.
I would love it if this solution would contain Streams.

Data:

```
public class Request{
    private int id;
    private List<Action> actions;

    public List<Action> getActions(){
        return actions;
    }

}

public class Action{
    private int id;
    private String comment;
    private ActionEnum actionEnum;

    public ActionEnum getAction(){
        return actionEnum;
    }

}

public enum ActionEnum {
    ACCEPTED, DENIED, OPEN
}
```

My Solution:

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var allRequests = new ArrayList<Request>();
        var result = new ArrayList<>(allRequests);
        for (Request request : allRequests) {
            for (Action action : request.getActions()) {
                if (action.getAction().equals(ActionEnum.DENIED)) {
                    result.remove(request);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using streams

```
List<Request> result = allRequests.stream().filter(request ->request.getActions()
                .streams.noneMatch(action->action.getAction().equals(ActionEnum.DENIED))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
List<Request> allRequests = List.of(request1, request2, request3, ...);
Predicate<Request> requestFilter = request -> request.getActions().stream()
   .noneMatch(action -> action.getActionEnum() == ActionEnum.DENIED);
List<Request> filteredRequests = allRequests.stream().filter(requestFilter).collect(Collectors.toList());
```